# quarantine mailbox not receiving quarantined items exchange 2010 anti-spam content filtering

Tags: exchange, exchange-2010, spam, content-filter

On exchange 2010, i have the anti-spam features installed on the hub transport.
I have the content filtering enabled, with quarantine if the scl is higher than 7. this is the only option i have turned on for content filtering

i have the quarantine mailbox set to my abuse@domain.com mailbox

however - none of the quarantined messages are being sent to that mailbox - and im not sure why.

any help in figuring this out is appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This](http://blogs.technet.com/b/exchange/archive/2010/01/13/3409181.aspx) should give you a good starting point.